# android: setting a button programmatically using setX and setY

Tags: android, view, android-relativelayout, coordinate

```
public class Game_collecting_view extends View 
{
    Button image_boy;
    private static final int BOY_DIAMETER = 200; // initial spot size
    int boy_width =0;
    int boy_height =0;

   public void setGame_collecting(Game_collecting mGame_collecting)
   {
       this.mGame_collecting = mGame_collecting;
   }    

   // constructs a new View
   public Game_collecting_view(Context context, RelativeLayout parentLayout)
   {    
       super(context);
      resources = context.getResources(); // save Resources for loading external values
      layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      // get references to various GUI components
      relativeLayout = parentLayout;
      spotHandler = new Handler(); // used to add spots when game starts

   } 

   @Override
   protected void onSizeChanged(int width, int height, int oldw, int oldh)
   {
      viewWidth = width; // save the new width
      viewHeight = height; // save the new height
   } 

   public void set_boy()
   {
          final Button boy = (Button) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.untouched, null);
          boy.setX(viewWidth /2); 
          boy.setY(viewHeight - BOY_DIAMETER); 
          boy.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
          boy.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue);         
          boy.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(BOY_DIAMETER, BOY_DIAMETER));
          relativeLayout.addView(boy); // add spot to the screen

          Toast.makeText(getContext(), "set_boy\nviewWidth=" +viewHeight +"\nviewHeight=" +viewHeight, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          boy.setOnClickListener
          ( 
             new OnClickListener()
             {            
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                   touchedSpot(boy); 
                } 
             }  
          ); 
   }

   public void resume(Context context)
   {
         resetGame();
   } 

   public void resetGame()
   {
      for (int i = 1; i <= INITIAL_SPOTS; ++i)
      {
          spotHandler.postDelayed(addSpotRunnable, i * SPOT_DELAY);
          generate_text();
      }          
      set_boy();
   } 

   private Runnable addSpotRunnable = new Runnable()
   {
      public void run()
      {
         addNewSpot(); // add a new spot to the game
      } 
   };
```

## Objective:

I would like to set the boy icon at the bottom middle of the screen.
The boy icon is set at this way for later dynamic interface (swipe the screen to the right the boy icon will move to the right, vice versa)

## Observation:

The toast reports both the viewWidth and viewHeight =0, and the boy icon appears at 0,0 (left upper corner). If I set the setY(viewHeight + BOY_DIAMETER), the boy icon will be located at (0, 200).

## Question:

I would like to ask why the viewWidth and viewHeight both report 0. How could the `onSizeChanged` be called immediately such that the boy icone could be set at the bottom center of the screen?

Thanks!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932253/get-positions-of-views-in-a-dialog-relativ-to-their-parent/19933242#19933242 check my answer here

Comment: you are askig the size too early, before the elements are laid out on the screen.

Comment: @njzk2: properly you are right, I now have using `getViewTreeObserver()` to derive the `ViewWidth` and `ViewHeight` before going through the `setX` and `setY`. Yet the boy icon still locating at (0,0). I tried if using `setX(720/2)` and `setY(1134-200)` it is probably located at the desired place. That means the `viewWidth` and `viewHeight` are not yet received before setting the boy icon....in that way how could I defer positioning the boy icon? using `Handler` How do I know when the dimension is retrieved?

Comment: you could use the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#widthPixels properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location is null until Android has calculated their positions. You can retrieve the height and width like this:

```
image_boy.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int height = image_boy.getHeight();
            int width = image_boy.getWidth(); 
            //these values won't be null
        }
    });
```

Comment: i have used this `getViewTreeObserver()` for getting the relativelayout's height and width instead and it works now =)

Answer (score 0):

set layout param for setting the view position

Comment: set layout param? `boy.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(BOY_DIAMETER, BOY_DIAMETER));`