# ImageView onTouch never fired when animation was used

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener

I use a phone with Android 2.3 and an animation to move an `ImageView`.

Here is the animation:

```
TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0,  xDest, yDest, yDest);
anim.setDuration(1000);
anim.setFillAfter(true);
MoveImagesOutsideOfScreen();
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
view.startAnimation(anim);
```

After the animation, when I use the following code to detect touch on my imageview and move it, nothing happens:

```
ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageSimple);
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
{
  PointF DownPT = new PointF(); // Record Mouse Position When Pressed Down
  PointF StartPT = new PointF(); // Record Start Position of 'img'
  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
  {
    Log.i(TAG,"Touch started");
    int eid = event.getAction();

    switch (eid)
    {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        PointF mv = new PointF(event.getX() - DownPT.x, event.getY() - DownPT.y);
        v.setX((int) (StartPT.x + mv.x));
        v.setY((int) (StartPT.y + mv.y));
        StartPT = new PointF(v.getX(), v.getY());
        Log.i(TAG,"Moved ");
      break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        DownPT.x = event.getX();
        DownPT.y = event.getY();
            StartPT = new PointF(v.getX(), v.getY());
            break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        // Nothing have to do
      break;
      default:
      break;
    }
    return true;
  }
});
```

I checked the log and the message *Touch started* was never shown. What prevents it?

**UPDATE**: Holy @%*! It seems that an animation doesn't move the actual view but instead some sort of copy (I don't see the concept of it, I think creating a copy is wasteful and most of the times people want to use the moved object).

I saved the layout params at the `onCreate`, and when I set it back, my views are placed randomly. What should I do to make my view be there where the animation puts its wasteful twin?

```
paramsSimple= (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) aq.id(R.id.imageSimple).getImageView().getLayoutParams();
paramsExpert= (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) aq.id(R.id.imageExpert).getImageView().getLayoutParams();


public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
{
  view.setLayoutParams(view.getId()==R.id.imageSimple?paramsSimple:paramsExpert);
}
```

Comment: You said that your views are placed randomly. Try to see what layout parameters are returned either via `Log` or `Toast`.

Comment: I will do, but shouldn't a saved layout look like when it was saved? Random might be a little bit strong, it just places the views very off.

Comment: I am guessing that the views' parameters returned are zero. Tell me if I am right.

Comment: I'll check it in a few hours. If I recall correctly, they are not 0s.

Comment: Yes, they are 0s. My views are placed invisibly on the layout then on animation they moved outside the view and moved to the center. Where should I save the layout params?

Comment: I added the following code in animationEnd and my view is hardly visible (from the left, I see the last 30dp of it but left margin should set the left side). I don't understand how Android animation and layouts operate: 
        params.setMargins(30,40,0,0);
        view.setLayoutParams(params);

Comment: Now it seems that the image is in the right position but its visible clone is off. How can I synchronize the view and its ghost? It becomes a nightmare.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932253/get-positions-of-views-in-a-dialog-relativ-to-their-parent/19933242#19933242