# Android: onTouchListener not working during animation

Tags: java, android, animation, ontouchlistener

I'm having a problem with my on touch listener - it works fine when the animation isn't running but wont work during the animation.

In case it is relevant the only method I'm using is the onFling() method.

I set up the touch listener and animation(to make an image view move down the screen):

```
    image.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });
```

and the Animation:

```
Animation moveDown = new TranslateAnimation(image.getX(), image.getX(), 0, pxHeight-pxImageHeight/2);
```

I have an onAnimationListener set up and have tried moving the onTouchListener to different parts of the code (such as onCreate, the onStart method of the animation and others)

In short, I want to be able to swipe my image during the animation of the imageView moving down the screen

Thanks

Comment: this question may shed some light: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20458937/imageview-ontouch-never-fired-if-animation-was-used

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still confused as to how to fix the problem.
The gesture detection seems to be working if I swipe at the top of the screen (where the image was originally) but I can't work out to make it work on the image at its current location during the animation