# Calculate expected LayoutParams of child view without adding to ViewGroup

Tags: android, animation, layout

### Background

---

To learn animations, I'm creating a Towers of Hanoi type of game.  **My main goal is to animate the movement of the block from one tower to another.**  I've got the following layout

```
  |------RelativeLayout------|
  |-Linear-|-Linear-|-Linear-|
  |-Block1-|-----------------|
  |-Block2-|-----------------|
  |-Block3-|-----------------|
  |--------------------------|
ID| Tower1 | Tower2 | Tower3 |
```

I've set the XML attribute `android:clipChildren="false"` on every ViewGroup.

For example, if I tried to animate the movement of `Block1` from `Tower1` to `Tower2` using `Block1.animate().setDuration(3000).translationX(1000)`.  As the layout is right now, `Block1` will animate within `Tower1`, but **`Block1` gets clipped** the second it leaves `Tower1`.

I've played with changing the z-order by adding the blocks last in the XML file.  It doesn't reliably work, though.

To ensure animations don't get clipped, I've decided to add a copy of the `Block1` (named `copyBlock`) to the root RelativeLayout, position `copyBlock` on top of `Block1`, and animate it to the destination `Tower2` (defined in coordinates)

To get the destination coordinates, I was planning on adding an invisible `copyBlock` to `Tower2`, then get the coordinates.  This way, I can take advantage of the **LinearLayout's layout functions to account for matters such as padding, gravity, etc**.  Otherwise, I'll have to get the position of `Tower2`, calculate the topmost block, adjust the coordinates of `Block1` so that it'll be on top of the topmost block and centered.

But, I'm pretty sure this way is hacky, and there's a better way

### Questions

---

- **How can I get the above destination coordinates without having to add an invisible view to the destination tower?**  Is there a way to ask for a "prelayout" without having to add View to the layout?
- Do you have any explanations for why the animation gets clipped?  Is there a better way to approach this rather than adding a new view to the root RelativeLayout ViewGroup?

Comment: You can easily get the coordinates of Tower2 and Tower3. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932253/get-positions-of-views-in-a-dialog-relativ-to-their-parent/19933242#19933242

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

1- You can't overcome the clipping issue, because you are trying to move the child beyond the parent dimensions, unless you are moving within the same parent.

2- Use `FrameLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` so you can control views margins correctly;

3- You can get the destination coordinates by knowing the height of the root layout and width, its seems the towers width are equal, so the (total width/3) will give the cell width then get the `X` coordinate, and the (total height -  cell height ) will give the `Y` coordinate of the tower ( assuming you have the tower hight)

Comment: 2) Can you clarify what you mean by this?  Are you referring to the positioning of the ViewGroups?

1) This clarified a lot for me.  I was seeing erratic behavior.  Turns out that the Z order will actually "matter" if you're animating within the same parent

Comment: 2) ok, within `FrameLayout` you can move `Views` just by changing its `topMargin` and `leftMargin` as (x,y)

Comment: you can change the `Z` order of a `View` by calling `view.bringToFront()`