# Find coordinates of a textView

Tags: android

I currently have two `textView` objects in android, one is a simple `textView` with the text "TextView" (`android:id="@+id/touchView"`), and the last is a `textView` I would like to manipulate and is the focus of this question (`android:id="@+id/viewLocat"`).

My goal is to have the textView `viewLocat` display the coordinates of the position of the textView `touchView` once the activity has been started.

**Updated** This is what I have tried so far (my `.java` file is shown below)

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View touchView = findViewById(R.id.touchView);
        View viewLocat = findViewById(R.id.viewLocat);
        int[] viewLocation = new int[2];
        touchView.getLocationOnScreen(viewLocation);
        viewLocat.setText("x: " + viewLocation[0] + " y: " + viewLocation[1]);


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;

    }

}
```

Comment: From what I see now, you have just created an activity and nothing else. You have to initialize all the text views and all. Then please google "android get view margins". I think you'll find what you need.

Comment: Or take a look at View.getLeft(), View.getRight(), View.getTop(), and View.getBottom()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a reference to the controls like so:

```
View touchView = findViewById(R.id.touchView);
View viewLocat = findViewById(R.id.viewLocat);
```

Once you have a reference to your views you can get the location to them like this:

```
int[] viewLocation = new int[2];
touchView.getLocationOnScreen(viewLocation);
```

The int array is populated with the co-ordinates of the view in relation to the screen, regardless of where it is in relation to its parents.

Then, just update the text in viewLocat to show the coordinates:

```
viewLocat.setText("x: " + viewLocation[0] + " y: " + viewLocation[1]);
```

This should get you started, but I'll leave you to figure out which event needs to cause the text to be updated.

Comment: the output is always 0, 0. Do you know why this is happening? I even tried adding a `view` above the `textview` objects to take up space, but the output is still 0, 0.

Comment: Hmm never seen this myself, but take a look at the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932253/get-positions-of-views-in-a-dialog-relativ-to-their-parent it might apply to your problem too.